# I have a trouble with my Login Authentication Servlet

Tags: java, mysql, servlets, authentication

i have a problem with my login authentication login.jsp
I have a class UsuarioLogin:

```
  package br.com.cad.dao;

import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;

import br.com.cad.basica.Contato;

public class UsuarioLogin {
private Contato usuario;

    public UsuarioLogin(Contato usr)
    {
        usuario=usr;
    }

        public boolean verificaLogin(){

        if(usuario.getEmail()!=null && usuario.getSenha()!=null)
        {
            try
            {
             ConnectDb con = new ConnectDb();
             String strsql="SELECT PF_EMAIL, PF_SENHA FROM DADOS_CADASTRO WHERE PF_EMAIL = ? and PF_SENHA = ?;";       
             PreparedStatement stmt = con.getConnection().prepareStatement(strsql);
             stmt.setString(1, usuario.getEmail());
             stmt.setString(2, usuario.getSenha());
             boolean logado = false;
             ResultSet rs=stmt.executeQuery();



             rs.close();
             stmt.close();
             return  logado;
            }
            catch (SQLException e) 

        {  
                e.printStackTrace(); 
                return false;
            }

        }
        return false;

}}
```

and my Servlet LoginAuthentication:

```
package br.com.cad.servlet;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

import javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;

import br.com.cad.basica.Contato;
import br.com.cad.dao.UsuarioLogin;


public class LoginAuthentication extends HttpServlet {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        try {

        } finally {            
            out.close();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        String email=request.getParameter("email");
        String senha=request.getParameter("password");
        RequestDispatcher rd = null;
        Contato user = new Contato();
        user.setEmail(email);
        user.setSenha(senha);
        UsuarioLogin ul = new UsuarioLogin(user);
        if(ul.verificaLogin())
        {
            HttpSession sessao = request.getSession();
            sessao.setAttribute("USER",email);
            rd=request.getRequestDispatcher("logado.jsp");
            rd.forward(request,response);
        }
        else
        {
            request.setAttribute("msg", "Usuário ou senha inválidos");
            rd=request.getRequestDispatcher("login.jsp");
            rd.forward(request,response);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        doGet(request,response);
    }

    @Override
    public String getServletInfo() {
        return "Short description";
    }// </editor-fold>
}
```

But i don't know how i got a user or password invalid if i entered a valid e-mail and pass!!! please somone can help me?

Comment: For those who do not speak (or guess) Portuguese, it would have been nice to translate your code. To answer your question, you have this result because `ul.verificaLogin()` returns false. What have you tried to debug this method?

Answer (score 0):

I guess the `loganto` is the boolean flag indicating that a user is logged in or not.

The problem in your code is that you execute the `Select` query but you never check if a record was found. You can do it like this:

```
ResultSet rs=stmt.executeQuery();
while(rs.next()){
  loganto=true; //a valid record was found so return true
}
rs.close();
return loganto;
```

Comment: now my code is but dont works:boolean logado = false;
             ResultSet rs=stmt.executeQuery();
             
             while(rs.next()){
               logado=true; //a valid record was found so return true
             }
             rs.close();
             stmt.close();
             return logado;
                    
             
             }
            catch (SQLException e) 
            
        {  
             e.printStackTrace(); 
             return false;
            }

        }
        return false;

}}

Comment: No i dont get exception simply dont works return a msg email or password invalids!

Comment: come on, I am sure you can do some debugging and tell us what doesn't work. Does it executes the sql? does it find results? What....?